# Access to string.xml Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need to access to the string.xml on the Resources folder to made my multilingual app.

I'm trying to find a way to do it. It should be simple but I didn't find and answer. This is my `string.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<resources xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <string name="Text">Text</string>
</resources>
```

I need to set the property text to my button. I try this but it doesn't work.

```
<Button x:Name="btn" Text="@string/Text"/>
```

Also I need to set the property by programmability. Somo thing like:

```
btn.Text=Resources.GetString(Resource.String.Text);
```

How could I do it?

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need to use `string.xml` to localize your app? If I'm not mistaken `string.xml` is only available on Android and given the fact that you are using Xamarin.Forms I assume you will target iOS as well. Then will you create a separate resource file for iOS? I don't think this is how you should localize your apps. My suggestion is to forget about `string.xml` and store your localized strings in `.resx` files. Check out: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/localization/text?pivots=windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use resource file like this in xamarin.forms. Check this article this will help you:

1. https://xamgirl.com/handle-multilingual-in-xamarin-forms-without-any-plugin/
2. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-forms-multiligual/

What you have done, we normally follow in Xamarin.Android project not in Xamarin.Forms.

Answer (score 0):

**yor string.xml file**

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">My Application</string>
    <string name="Text">Text</string>
</resources>
```

**then you can add a button in an XML file like-**

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Text" />
```

Comment: Op didn't ask how to do it on Android. They wanted to know how to use resources in Xamarin.Forms.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do that with Strings.xml on Android, get the text value from MainActivity and pass the text as parameter to the MainPage.

Create the different Strings.xml file for different language.

Default: values/Strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
 <string name="app_name">Default</string>
 <string name="taskcancel">Cancel</string>
</resources>
```

Spanish: values-es/Strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
 <string name="app_name">Spanish</string>
 <string name="taskcancel">Cancelar</string>
</resources>
```

MainActivity:

```
 public string STR { get; set; }
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        STR = Resources.GetText(Resource.String.taskcancel);
        LoadApplication(new App(STR));
    }
```

App.xaml.cs:

```
   public App(string text)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new MainPage(text);
    }
```

MainPage:

```
    public MainPage(string text)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        label.Text = text; 
    }
```